# Scrapy response returns an empty array

Tags: python, shell, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy

I'm crawling this [page](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvekey.cgi?keyword=hp) with scrapy and I'm trying to extract all the rows of the main table.

The following *XPath* expression should give me the wanted result:

```
//div[@id='TableWithRules']//tbody/tr
```

Testing with the scrap shell made me notice that this expression does return an empty array:

```
#This response is empty: []
response.xpath("//div[@id='TableWithRules']//tbody").extract()
#This one is not:
response.xpath("//div[@id='TableWithRules']//thead").extract()
```

I guess the website owners tries to limit the scraping of the table data but is there any way to find a work-around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you are trying to query a non-existing element.  The `tbody` element is often injected into the html by the browser and actually doesn't exist in the source html prior to being rendered.  You can see this if you inspect the page source.

A possible workaround to get all of the rows would be to simply bypass the `tbody` tag and query the rows directly:

Example:
`scrapy shell https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvekey.cgi?keyword=hp`

```
In [1]: rows = response.xpath("//div[@id='TableWithRules']//tr")

In [2]: len(rows)
Out[2]: 3366
```

Or if you wanted to skip the header row then you could do.

```
In [1]: rows = response.xpath("//div[@id='TableWithRules']//tr[td]")

In [2]: len(rows)
Out[2]: 3365
```

Answer (score 1):

If you run this JavaScript in the console, it will extract all names and descriptions from the page.

```
let trs = document.querySelectorAll('#TableWithRules tbody tr')

trs.forEach((el) => {
    let tds = el.querySelectorAll('td')
    let name = tds[0].innerText;
    let description = tds[1].innerText;
    console.log(name, description)
})
```

The same code using **Selenium**, for example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvekey.cgi?keyword=hp")

trs = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='TableWithRules']//tbody//tr")
for tr in trs:
    tds = tr.find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//td")
    name = tds[0].text
    description = tds[1].text
    print(name, description)

driver.close()
```

**Output**

```
...
CVE-1999-0016 Land IP denial of service.
CVE-1999-0014 Unauthorized privileged access or denial of service via dtappgather program in CDE.
CVE-1999-0011 Denial of Service vulnerabilities in BIND 4.9 and BIND 8 Releases via CNAME record and zone transfer.
CVE-1999-0010 Denial of Service vulnerability in BIND 8 Releases via maliciously formatted DNS messages.
CVE-1999-0009 Inverse query buffer overflow in BIND 4.9 and BIND 8 Releases.
...
```

**Code Explanation**

Initially, retrieve all `tr` elements from the `tbody` within the `#TableWithRules` table. Then, construct a for loop to iterate over these `tr` elements, extracting all `td` elements contained within. Typically, there are two `td` elements: one for the `name` and another for the `description`. Proceed to obtain the text from `td[0]` and `td[1]`.

**What about the 'THEAD'?**

The process for `THEAD` is similar to that described above. The primary difference lies in targeting `THEAD` instead of `TBODY`, and focusing on `th` elements rather than `td`.